# Knockout: Values in attr: tags not retrived

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-binding, knockout.js

So i have this issue. I am trying to create a google map search example in knockout.js.
My ViewModel is as follows:

```
function search() {
    var self = this;
    self.loc = ko.observable();

    self.load = function () {
        $.getJSON("http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON?q=" +  $('#q').val() + "&maxRows=10",self.loc);

    self.centre = function (lat,lng){
  var point = new GLatLng(lat,lng);
  map.setCenter(point,13);
}

    }


$(document).ready(function(){
    ko.applyBindings(new search());
});

function center(lat,lng){
  var point = new GLatLng(lat,lng);
  map.setCenter(point,13);
}
```

And the View is as following:

```
<div data-bind="with: loc">
    <div data-bind="foreach: geonames">
        <a data-bind="text: name, attr: { 'data-lat': 'lat', 'data.lng': 'lng', 'href': 'javascript:center(lat,lng);' }"></a>

    </div>
</div>
```

The problem I am facing is that the lat and lng fields are not being retrieved from the fetched JSON. Instead , they are displayed as is .For instance in the resultant html source, the href attribute of the  tag would contain javascript:center(lat,lng) instead of numerical values for lat lng. But the 'name' item from the text data-bind field is displayed correctly.

I'm guessing the issue is in putting the key: value pair in single quotes but if i remove them, I get various invalid taken found errors pertaining to - in data-lat attribute or . in data.lng or : in javascript:center(lat,lng); tag .
Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're values in the attr tags don't work because they are in quotes.  Also, I'm not sure why you need to have the href call a JS function, when you can use Knockout's `click` binding to call a function in your `search()` model.

Not all of you're code was present, so I made some assumptions, but I think this JS Fiddle does what you want.
http://jsfiddle.net/KQrEF/1/

I changed your code a bit, but you may need more of the info back.

JS:

```
function search() {
    var self = this;
    self.loc = ko.observable();

    self.load = function () {
        //I hardcoded 10 here because whatever you were using wasn't present in what you posted.
        $.getJSON("http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON?q=" + '10' + "&maxRows=10", self.loc);
    };

    self.centre = function (lat, lng, loc) {
        //logging these to show that it gets what you want
        console.log('lat',lat);
        console.log('lng',lng);
        console.log('loc',loc);
        //errors here because GLatLng isn't in what you posted
        var point = new GLatLng(lat, lng);
        map.setCenter(point, 13);

    };

}

$(document).ready(function () {
    //creating a variable search so we can call search.load() later
    search = new search();
    ko.applyBindings(search);
    search.load();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="with: loc">
    <div data-bind="foreach: geonames"> 
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.centre.bind($data,lat,lng), text: name"></a>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your reply didn't solve my question but it did help me in reaching a solution. I used an href attribute in an <a> tag because i wanted to create hyperlinks.
However i achieved the same functionality by using buttons and it worked !
So cheer :)